# How to detect dynamic library loads

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to detect what dynamic libraries an app loads at runtime? I've looked through Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001908-SW1) for dynamic libraries but it doesn't seem to discuss this.

Comment: It would be useful to know *why* you want to do this. For your own application, it's not particularly-hard to know which libraries are loaded, but due to the application sandboxing on iOS, I don't think you'll be able to determine anything about the libraries loaded by other applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of all libraries loaded at runtime by your application:

```
// import the dynamic linker API
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>

// After your application finishes launching, maybe in 
// -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
int imageCount = _dyld_image_count();
for (int i=0; i < imageCount; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d - %s", i, _dyld_get_image_name(i));
}
```

If you want to call a function each time a library is loaded, you can use `_dyld_register_func_for_add_image()` or `_dyld_register_func_for_link_module()`

**Important note** I only checked this in the simulator. I believe it should work on-device, but I have other things I need to work on right now.

Apple Documentation starts here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/

There's an interesting blog article about walking the mach header information here:

http://ddeville.me/2014/04/dynamic-linking/

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Where did you find this function in the documentation? Also, would there be any issues in moving this code into a `Static Library` so that I could drop it in and link to it in any of my apps, to print out their dynamic libraries?

Comment: Thank you for finding that ability to register call backs.

Comment: @MarkBessey perhaps you could take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782619/saving-char-and-intptr-t-in-objective-c

Comment: @MarkBessey my main problem now is that your above solution solves the problem of logging the paths, but I also need access to the base address

Comment: See the edits to the answer for a couple of good starting places. I hate to say it, but I actually just opened dyld.h and then looked at the man pages for the likely-looking functions. Knowing what things are *called* is usually about 80% of the battle in OS X and iOS programming.

Comment: @MarkBessey Thanks for all your help. Last night I actually came upon that dynamic linking article myself, and it solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 1):

A.

You can log the loading event as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/LoggingDynamicLoaderEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002077-SW1).

> This article identifies the environment variables you can set and the type of dynamic loader logging they activate.

You can set the env with the *Product* | *Scheme* | *Edit Scheme…* menu and then in the sheet *Run* | *Environment*.

So you cannot "access" it in your app. The app (to be more precise: the runtime environment) simply logs the event without any code in your app.

B.

A dynamic library itself can detect its loading through the [`+load`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load) method on a per class resp. per category basis.

I do not think that there is a notification or something like this for the app itself to get notified, when a call leads to a dynamic load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did see that in the documentation but I wasn't sure how to use it. For example, if I create a new single view app, and then put `NSLog(@"%@",DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES);` in the viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad`, it says that the variable is undefined. Do you know how to access it?

Comment: I added an explanation. Likely it is not what you want.

Comment: what do you think about Mark's solution above?

Comment: I think that it is great. I needed that in the past (some years ago), but unfortunately I did not find it.

Comment: would you know how to print the base address as well?