# Saving char* and intptr_t in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to save a `const char*` and a `const intptr_t` so that I can save dynamic library loads. I'm currently using the following code to log dynamic library loads:

```
+ (void)startRecording {
//    NSArray *oldLibs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self returnFilePathWithName:@"dynamic_libraries"]];
//    NSLog(@"start recording");
//    NSLog(@"oldLibs: %@", oldLibs);
    _dyld_register_func_for_add_image(&image_added);
    _dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(&image_removed);
}

static void image_added(const struct mach_header *mh, intptr_t slide)
{
    _print_image(mh, true);
}

static void image_removed(const struct mach_header *mh, intptr_t slide)
{
    _print_image(mh, false);
}

static void _print_image(const struct mach_header *mh, bool added)
{
    Dl_info image_info;
    int result = dladdr(mh, &image_info);

    if (result == 0) {
        printf("Could not print info for mach_header: %p\n\n", mh);
        return;
    }

    const char *image_name = image_info.dli_fname;
    const intptr_t image_base_address = (intptr_t)image_info.dli_fbase;

    const char *log = added ? "Added" : "Removed";
    printf("%s: 0x%02lx %s\n\n", log, image_base_address, image_name);

    //    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:image_name];
    //    NSNumber *baseAddress = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:image_base_address];
}
```

I know that I can convert `image_name` and `image_base_address` into Objective-C objects, but where/when should I save them?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What exactly do you mean by "save"? Do you want to retrieve the values while your program is running, or save them to disk and load them again when your app runs again, or what? I mean, they're just variables, you handle them the same as any other variable...

Comment: @KurtRevis I want to save them to disk and load them again later. Am I allowed to use NSObjects in a C function? I was planning on using NSKeyedArchiver to save them to disk. Also, I don't know how to call class methods outside of this C function, since I can't pass a reference to self. I tried setting it as a static variable with type `id` but it doesn't know the method exists then.

Comment: If this is all in one `.m` file, you can call Objective-C code from inside your C functions, yes. And you don't need a `self` to call class methods -- you just write `[YourClass startRecording]`, for instance.

Comment: @KurtRevis Ok great. Thank you. What do you think is the fastest way to read/write from disk. I was planning on using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. What do you think? I asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795457/fastest-way-to-write-to-disk-ios

Answer (score 1):

Pointers will typically have different values each time a program is run, and trying to save and restore them will typically lead to a total and utter disaster.

If you want to save and restore the result of _dyld_register_func_for_add_image, that's even worse, because *you need to call that function*. It does things. It doesn't just return a pointer. Without the call, that pointer would be totally useless.