# Fastest way to write to disk - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'm working with a C function and want to persist data to disk. What's the fastest way to read and write this data. I was converting the `char*` and `intptr_t` to `NSString` and `NSNumber`, storing them in a dictionary and then storing each dictionary into an `NSMutableArray`. However, is there a faster way to store this data without the need to wrap the values in Objective-C objects?

```
static void _print_image(const struct mach_header *mh, bool added)
{
    Dl_info image_info;
    int result = dladdr(mh, &image_info);

    if (result == 0) {
        printf("Could not print info for mach_header: %p\n\n", mh);
        return;
    }

    const char *image_name = image_info.dli_fname;
    const intptr_t image_base_address = (intptr_t)image_info.dli_fbase;

    const char *log = added ? "Added" : "Removed";
    //printf("%s: 0x%02lx %s\n\n", log, image_base_address, image_name);

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:image_name];
    NSNumber *baseAddress = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:image_base_address];
    NSDictionary *info = @{@"imageName" : imageName, @"baseAddress" : baseAddress};
    [arr addObject:info];
}
```

Comment: Does it really matter? Is this a performance bottleneck in your system? I recommend keeping code simple and only focusing on optimizations / fancy code where there are problems.

Comment: @Chris Well yes, it's logging output on launch of my app, and so I want it to impact launch time as little as possible.

Comment: Yes, but how much of that time is I/O, and how much of that is CPU doing the type conversions in Objective-C? Based on my experience, nearly all of the time is spent doing the actual I/O.

Comment: Are you still trying this? Good luck reading and reusing the baseAddress. I've rarely seen anyone that misguided.