# Count dynamic libraries loadings

Tags: c, unix, dll

I need to make a C dynamic library (DL, with extension `.so`), which can count how many programs have loaded it at runtime. I guess, the DL have something like `_dyld_image_count` from [How to detect dynamic library loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759368/how-to-detect-dynamic-library-loads), but I can't find it.

I mean, how does the DL react to 
`void  *dlopen(const char *, int);`?

Am I right when I say that it's impossible to have a variable inside a DL, and increment it with a DL's function call from programs?

Comment: Since each process that uses a shared library gets its own private copy of any variables defined by the library, you cannot usefully store a use-count in a variable defined in a library. Your best bet might be an initializer function that arranges to append to, or maybe rewrite, a log file that records how often it was used.  A.log file can record more useful information (process ID, user ID, time, etc) as well as the simple use count. I believe (but stand to be proved wrong) that there are functions that are run when the library is loaded, but you'll need to read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Note that the question you refer to applies to iOS, the o/s used by iPhones and iPads.  It might also be available on macOS (Mac OS X), but it probably doesn't apply to general Unix systems.  That code is also for counting the number of dynamic libraries loaded in a particular program, not the number of different programs that load a particular dynamic library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the information!