# How to detect dynamic library loads xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have xamairn iOS an app which contains jail break detection code.
I also want to detect if any dynamic library loads to app.

I have found below code from this link : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759368/how-to-detect-dynamic-library-loads)
but don't know how to do it in xamarin ios

Comment: Xamarin.iOS does not expose that api , you can try to create binding library with the code in that link and then use it in Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks @ColeX-MSFT . I will try that